# Ubuntu 15.04 brightness doesn't work

Tags: lenovo, brightness, 15.04

brightness on my 
Lenovo-IdeaPad-P400-touch graphic Intel® Ivybridge Mobile os type 64-bit Ubuntu 15.04 doesn't increase or decrease after updating from 14.04 
please help!!!

Comment: what does `ls /sys/class/backlight` show?

Comment: hey it show ideapad  intel_backlight
and thanks for the replay!!

Comment: I have the same problem ):

Answer (score 0):

Create this file:

`gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/80-backlight.conf`

and put the below contents into it and save it.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "AccelMethod"     "sna"
    Option      "Backlight"       "intel_backlight" # use your backlight that works here
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Reboot and  see if this solves your problem.

Comment: still the same nothing change!!!